# Как добавить функцию программы на python в контекстное меню с помощью самого python?

Tags: python, linux, windows, текст, выделение-текста

К примеру, я выделяю какую-нибудь строку не в самой программе, а в любом месте, в браузере или в текстовом редакторе. Хочу с помощью контекстного меню, нажав правой кнопкой мыши на выделенный текст, выбрать соответствующий пункт меню и как-то взаимодействовать с выделенным текстом с помощью python. И также непонятно - как добавить этот пункт меню инструментами самого python? Нужно, чтобы было кроссплатформенное решение, которое могло работать с разными дистрибьютивами линукс.

Comment: Реализация выделения текста в разных программах разная. Для браузеров проще использовать системы плагинов, для этого они и создавались. Для других программ: изучайте reverse engineering чтобы цепляться к процессу и отслеживать когда в программе выделяется что-то.

Comment: reverse engineering не нужен. выделенный текст дергается через "специальные возможности" (та штука для людей с ограниченными возможностями)

Comment: @eri подскажите, как пользоваться ими в dwm, i3 и прочих DM: "Нужно, чтобы было кроссплатформенное решение, которое могло работать с разными дистрибьютивами линукс."

Comment: Кроссплатформенно не получится.